# Dynamics AX 2012 R2 Enterprise Search on SharePoint Foundation 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013, search-engine, axapta

Did anyone got those two working together yet?

I got AX 2012 Enterprise Portal (EP) and Help Server working with SharePoint (SP) Foundation 2013, but I cant get AX Enterprise Search (ES) to work.

When I tried to install ES, asked me to install SharePoint Search first.

> SharePoint Search is not installed with Microsoft SharePoint
>   Foundation. To install Microsoft Search Server Express, go to
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=180385

However, as far as I know, Microsoft Search Server Express is included in SP 2013 by default.

So if it's already there, what path to the [Search Server URL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg731778.aspx) should I use instead of SP's 2010 default one (http://server_name/sites/DynamicsAXClientSearch/_vti_bin/search.asmx)? If I just use the root URL of EP I get this error:

> The service returned the following error: The HTTP request is
>   unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'. The
>   authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM'.

According to Microsoft, I should be able to use Search functionality in AX 2012 with SP 2013.

> All aspects of crawling, indexing, and retrieving Microsoft Dynamics
>   AX data and metadata for Search are performed by one of the following
>   products:
>
> - Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 or Microsoft SharePoint Server
> - 2010 Microsoft Search Server 2010 or Microsoft Search Server Express
> - 2010 Microsoft FAST Search Server 2010 Microsoft SharePoint
> - Foundation 2013 or Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013
>
> One of these products must be available in the computing environment
>   before you can install Enterprise Search.

But by following their installation documentation I still bump to the requirement of having Microsoft Search Server 2010 Express installed on my system, however its installation fails saying "Microsoft Search Server 2010 Express encountered an error during installation". UPDATE: For some reason installation worked on 3rd attempt and... seems like it ruined installation of SP 2013!

I feel like I'm really going in circles here.

---

**SOLUTION**: Got both versions (2010/2013) of SharePoint working with Dynamics AX 2012 R2. Please have a look at [my AX notes](http://donatas.xyz/dynamics-ax-enterprise-portal-search-help-server-sharepoint-setup.html) if you are facing same issues.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install SharePoint search as it says , 
It's not included in the standard SharePoint install , it's even a separte Download.